# How to place Joomla Shortcode in Template File

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

Seems the only way to get a shortcode to function in Joomla is via placing it in an article, unlike 'do_shortcode' in WordPress.

So, if my shortcode is for example, {msg userid=123}, how would I get it to dynamically grab the user id of the creator of the content?

I've tried the following, but no luck...

```
<?php
echo '<input type="hidden" id="userID" value="'.$resUid.'" />';
?>
```

along with the javascript...

```
<script>
    var uid = jQuery("#userID").val();
    jQuery(".content").append('{msg userid='+uid+'}');
alert('uid:'+uid);
</script>
```

I can understand why it doesn't work, but is there any other method that maybe I don't know about like 'do_shortcode' in WordPress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Joomla equivalent of do_shortcode is

```
$text = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $text);
```

Joomla doesn't implement short codes in the same way as WP. It runs content plugins on the article content, and the method above does the same thing for 3rd party extensions.

That being said, it doesn't sound like the problem you have has anything to do with shortcodes, nor does the code you posted seem to make any sense to me.  Perhaps you would be better off to change your question to explaining your real problem.

Comment: That worked!  Surprising that I couldn't find that info anywhere since it seems like something that would be a common need when doing custom Joomla work.  I re-worded the title into more of a question.  The code I wrote does make sense and work... it just doesn't 'execute'.  But that's kind of expected since it doesn't get 'prepared'.  Thanks for such a simple but perfect answer.